# CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, execution of AfterInsert

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I am getting the this error when I “Run All Tests” however the error disappears when I run test for individual classes. With All Tests most of the classes give same error.

***Error Details ***

> Error Message System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on
>   row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, trgOrphanId:
>   execution of AfterInsert
>
> caused by: System.QueryException: Record Currently Unavailable: The
>   record you are attempting to edit, or one of its related records, is
>   currently being modified by another user. Please try again.
>
> Trigger.trgOrphanId: line 23, column 1: [] Stack Trace
>   Class.testBatchDonorAllocation.myUnitTest: line 39, column 1

Comment: can you post your code to see the error line?

Comment: It may be due to one of the test class deleting or invoking a trigger with delete event.You may enable Parallel Apex Testing from options in 'Apex Test Execution' and then try to run all again.

Comment: thanks @baskaran, Disable Parallel Apex Testing worked. thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Setup's "Apex Test Execution" page there is an "Options" button that includes a "Disable Apex Parallel Testing" checkbox. Checking that will probably avoid the problem.

Comment: thanks Keith C, by disabling parallel testing, all the tests are now passing. Amazing!

thanks for help, you have saved my many hours and may be days. you are great.

Comment: @Mahmood In my experience where you have multiple tests touching the same SObject (which is pretty common in Salesforce code bases) the parallel testing runs you into this problem.

Comment: Keith C, will try to deploy change set to live. I hope it wouldn't throw error this time. thanks again

Comment: @Mahmood I think parallel testing is turned off for deployments to production.